# google play protect appeal download link problem

Tags: android

In the appeal form, there is a field for entering the download link AND NOT UPLOAD APK. Does anyone know what service will give me an acceptable link for that form?

Every link I tried has failed to be downloaded by the appeal form.
My app is not and not going to be in the play store. I do have a Plesk host but I couldn't make a site with an acceptable download link.

Example link download off my temporary wordpress site : https://aligator.ir/index.php/download/prayer-time/?wpdmdl=5&masterkey=5bcafa8ee3256

Comment: In what appeal form? Google Play? Why are you filling out an appeal for for an app that won't be on the Play Store?

Comment: the apps will be on other app markets but even so , 24 hours after build all apks from developers who are unknown , are added to a black list and when trying to install it , the installation gets blocked.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it and wrote a medium story about it: [Link](https://medium.com/@ali.gh2236/the-story-of-my-app-getting-blocked-by-google-play-protect-4784c83481be)

Comment: what did you put for additional info to support the appeal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill all details in this form.

> com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals

But they will ask download link, then you should upload the app to google firebase storage and copy the url of that file and paste it in the form.